# How to create instances of i18n module

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, internationalization, node-modules

I'm trying to create two instances of i18n module, but it doesn't work. Do you know how can make it?

```
var i18n = require('i18n')
var i18nInstance1 = new i18n()
var i18nInstance2 = new i18n()
```

**Error:**

```
var i18nInstance = new i18n();
                   ^

TypeError: i18n is not a constructor
```

Thank you so much.
Regards,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If it can help peoples, I've resolved my problem by using i18n-factory module.

For your information, when you require a module not create a singleton of it. If you want to has multiple instance, you have to privatify your logic or using a [factory pattern](http://www.dofactory.com/javascript/factory-method-design-pattern).

Answer (score 0):

There is said that to create instance you should use `I18n` module in documentation.

```
const i18nInstance = new I18n()
```

Comment: but it is in version from 0.12.0. Early there are not instances, Only singlenton